# Some architectural advice on ASP.NET MVC 3 replacement of php web site

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system

I am rewriting a web (application?).  I'll try to set things up, briefly (haha).  My client's website is built in with/in a CMS.  Most of it is static content.  The website is hosted somewhere but there is a login area for customers to track their orders and other dynamic business content which is stored on my client's servers.  Authentication happens on both sides (the [php] cms manages the session, but business logic and customer data including passwords resides on my client's servers in my client's database and is served up via wcf).  Each php request to the wcf webservice posts a json authentication string and if authenticated, my wcf webservice returns a json result populated with the requested data (which is then used with the smarty templates to generate an output that the cms sends to the browser).

This would all be fine except that the php code is monumental spaghetti.  Actually, it's probably not too bad by php standards, but I'm used to... well, who cares, because it comes down to the fact that I didn't write it, but I have to extend it, and each modification takes 10(0?) times longer than it should and only drowns the haystack in more noodles (to mix metaphors).  And damningly, there is no testing changes before they go live.  Any change or addition has to be made in the production environment (due to dependencies on the CMS environment).  So I have to mix blitz tactics with edit and pray, as well as keeping an 11th finger on the proverbial revert button (wouldn't it be nice if it were just a single step to revert?).  I have toyed with refactoring the php side many times, and have even written about 75% of a complete reimplementation.  But...

This web app is getting more and more responsibilities and change requests.  For this client I have written a 500,000 line ERP in C# and all their business logic resides therein.  So, I figure there is a definite ROI in having all their code in .NET, for me or whoever follows.

The only real constraint on any solution is that whatever the CMS is to display has to be appended to a variable "$output".  That leaves things pretty open.

Anyway, (the often superfluous but hopefully nerdly entertaining) narrative is complete.  So, with that, I have set up a simple php wrapper that uses cURL to get the contents of a url that is backed by my new mvc app.  That works fine for get.  My question is what is the best way to proceed with this.  Every request from the cms side needs to include some authentication information that it will retreive from a database (or whatever) and post with its request.  I figure I'll just cannibalize the wcf webservice and serve all content from within the mvc app.

So basically, what is the best way to write an mvc app where each request is a post that contains authentication information (it can be json or xml)?  I'm trying to avoid decorating every controller method with [HttpPost] and having every action method require an argument of my authentication dto so that at some point I can switch all authentication quickly and easily to asp forms authentication.

Thanks (for reading)!

Comment: I feel sorry for your client.

Comment: Why do you feel sorry for my client?

Comment: Because you don't understand why I feel sorry for your client.

Comment: There's that vase again.

Comment: I guess that's an insult then?  If so, could you enlighten me?  Or am I a lost cause?

Comment: Not so much an insult as a tongue in cheek response.  I feel sorry for your client if you talk to them the way you ask questions of us.  Consequently, since you don't understand that your writing style is.. umm.. different, then that is also a reason to feel sorry for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an action filter of your own, which will centrally detect the current logged in user and apply it to a parameter of your function.
Something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UserIDFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public bool Require { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Require)
        {
            if (Membership.GetUser() == null)
            {
                string formsAuthenticationToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["cookie"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formsAuthenticationToken))
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsAuthenticationToken);
                    if (ticket != null)
                    {
                        FormsIdentity identity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
                        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);
                        GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
                        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                    }
                }
                if (Membership.GetUser() == null)
                    throw new UserNotAuthenticatedException();
            }
        }
        const string key = "userId";
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
                filterContext.ActionParameters[key] = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            else
                filterContext.ActionParameters[key] = (Guid?)null;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And then decorate each action with:

```
[UserIDFilter]
(and the action will have 1st parameter: Guid? userId)
```

or

```
[UserIDFilter(Require=true)
(and the action will have 1st parameter: Guid userId)
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that I could insert at the beginning of the reception of a request from the cms side that would either authenticate and let the request pass through or deny the request altogether and send an error back to the cms side of things.  This way I could just decorate my controllers with [Authorize] or something like it so that when it comes time to ditch the cms altogether I can just switch over to the natural authentication.  And also so that I don't have to remember to decorate every action method.

Comment: 1) This solution denies request altogether if you're not authenticated (given that you set Require=true, or refactor to require all times).

Comment: What modifications would be needed so that I could decorate my controllers instead of my actions?  If I were to use this, you are saying that each method would need to have the GUID as a parameter.  Is that because I would need to do something with this manually in my method body, or is it just something that the ActionFilter would need?  (I'm new to MVC).  Thanks.

Comment: 2) You can decorate the controller itself, instead of each action. And then you won't forget.

Comment: Simply put that attribute above the controller (the class name).
If you don't put the userId parameter in your action, you'll just get the feature of revoking unauthenticated users. If you do put, you'll get the [correct and validated] userId right into your action.

Comment: So basically, on my PHP side I'll use setCookie("{someJSON}") and submit to my mvc backed url and this ActionFilter will use the cookie to authenticate the user and based on the success or failure of that route the action as specified in the url using whatever query string was provided?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. The code that I enlisted here works with ASP.NET Forms Authentication. If you apply other sort of authentication from your PHP code, you'll need of course to change the internal logic of my action filter method so it checks your cookie and retrieves (optionally) the current user identity. But anyway, this is the way to centralize user checking (or any other logic that should take place for every action or so) without manually adding code fragments to each controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

We know nothing of your CMS, we know nothing of your application, we know nothing of your architecture, we know nothing of your ERP... without knowing anything about anything it's a bit hard to give answers that mean anything.

Ofer attempted to give you a solution, but based on your response, the lack of information available didn't help him make the right assumptions about what you were looking for.

Imagine if someone came to you with your question, and imagine you know nothing about it.. could YOU figure out what you meant?

Also, I know you probably found your writing amusing, and perhaps it is.. but you seem to have put more effort into being amusing than you did in asking your actual question.  Those that answer questions tend to like it better when you try to make it as easy for them to answer as possible, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I do think I could figure out what I meant.  I attempted to specify the constraints placed upon the solution by the CMS.  Nothing needs to be known about the ERP other than it being written in .NET.  I spent the entire first paragraph explaining relevant architecture.  Perhaps rather than your borderline ad hominem you could simply ask for clarification relevant to your answer.  Ofer did attempt a solution (which I upvoted) and requested clarification of, pursuant with my ?.  However, since it used cookies instead of post data as requested in my question, I didn't mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like one of those situations, where the phrase: "To the man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail" very much applies.  You could not prevent yourself from adding a none too subtle dig at php, when you stated that the "CMS" code was spaghetti, although, not really, because as far as you're concerned PHP = spaghetti.

Please don't feign hurt feelings because people have called you out on the fact that your alleged question contains more narrative describing what things would be like in your perfect world, than it does actual relevant technical detail, or specific query.

The architecture where you are using PHP for absolutely nothing other than to make CURL calls to your .NET scripts is absurd.  Why waste our time, when your agenda is clear.  Go make your case to your client, as to why their investment in the microsoft tech stack is so much greater than anything else, that it makes sense for them to extend that stack to the front end.  We have plenty of excellent frameworks available in the PHP world that provide MVC.  It's quite clear that PHP is not in your comfort zone, and under the circumstances, it seems quite logical to make the case to the client that they are not well served by a hybrid solution.

Comment: Wow.  You too, eh?  You (probably) haven't the slightest idea.  The code IS spaghetti.  When you have functions that are 100s of lines long mixing SQL code in with HTML strings and a mini little web server that operates on "nouns verbs and adverbs" that restricts the extensibility of the system by requiring ever new english grammar knowledge-modifications and ever expanding arrays to handle business logic extensions...  The programmer who wrote it is one of those who thinks putting spaces between operators is an unnecessary luxury.  MVC & OOP are standards for a reason.

Comment: In any case I did not state that the CMS was spaghetti, I stated that the php code that dealt with this particular web app was spaghetti.

Comment: My understanding is that apache is a web server.  Why write another one that accomplishes nothing but distancing the solution from the problem?  That is why I refuse to work with it.  That and the fact that I can't test changes because of dependencies on a runtime environment.  Do you like to code in a situation where the only way to test a clients request is to upload code to a production server, log in with a real user's account and see if things are broken?  When hundreds of users are using the system in mission-almost-critical situations?  If so, then I feel sorry for your clients.

Comment: I understand there are frameworks in php that provide MVC.  I have used them.  Good and bad code can be written in most any language (think VB).   The point was this code IS bad, and rather than perpetuate my client's codebase being split between two languages by rewriting it in that same language, I should bring it over to a language that corresponds with the other 99.9% of his codebase.  As for my narrative, yeah, I'm so sorry for trying to be conversational in my expression of the problem.  I must have forgotten the baby-ish sensitivity to humanity that some programmers evince.

Comment: The only thing that's actually interesting to me in your statement is why " using PHP for absolutely nothing other than to make CURL calls to your .NET scripts is absurd".  That is what my "architectural" question was about.  Why is this absurd?  Like I said, this client's website is built in this CMS, so, in order to preserve the site's look and feel, it makes sense (to me) to simply inject the dynamic content into the existing site.  I see no reason to do otherwise.  Do YOU?  The difference between my solution and the current is that I would generate the tables and the forms from asp instead

Comment: What would be absurd in my view would be to write a php layer that forwards all business logic to a .net layer when that php layer could simply be replaced by a .net layer.  Right now I maintain a code generation layer to keep my php model in sync with my .net model.  And this was so that I wouldn't have to manually update associate array keys strewn all over files here and there.  I really don't understand where you are coming from.